# jquery fullcalendar: is init done?

Tags: jquery, initialization, fullcalendar

I use this function to change the date for one calender (jquery fullcalender by arshaw).

```
function cal_gotoDate(d){
    console.log('cal_gotoDate ' + curCal + ' ' + d);    
    $('#calendar'+curCal).fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
    cal_setTitle();
    return false;
}
```

The problem: The calender will be loaded dynamicaly by using ajax. It can happen that the calender is not loaded when the user tries to change the date. Therefore i got an error if they are not initialized:

```
TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
```

I would like to check if the fullcalender `$('#calendar'+curCal)` is initialized.

Comment: you can test something like if($.fn.fullCalendar) {...}

Answer (score 2):

I`m not sure that it is the best solution, but it works perfect - use fullcalendar [loading](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/loading/) callback and set global boolean flag, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var globalflag = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            //calendar initialization code
            loading: function (bool) { 
                if (!bool){
                    globalflag = true;
                }
                else{
                    globalflag = false;
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

and now you can check `globalflag` status.

For example I use loading callback for show/hide progress indicator.